# How to move swap near the beginning of the hard drive

Tags: partition, swap, lubuntu

Is it possible to move my swap closer to the beginning of the hard drive so that it swaps faster? Also, I have a Shuttle K45 originally released/made in 2008, which is the system in question. I have heard that if the "boot" partition isn't the 1st it won't boot, will this be an issue?
[image]

Comment: What does your partition table look like?

Comment: Did you see the picture? That's the current layout. If you can't, then here's it in words. The first partition (left to right) is 141.05GB big, with the flag "boot". After that is an Extended partition populated entirely by swap, which is 8GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for the Shuttle K45 question, but as for moving swap, the best approach is to do a backup and restore.

The problem is that moving swap will require changing the start position of the root partition, and that will wreck the filesystem on that partition. Modifying the end position of a partition is sometimes possible, but not so much with the start position.

So, I recommend backing up your root partition's filesystem, recreating your partitions as you want them, and then restoring the root partition's filesystem.

Comment: I'm not so sure where I heard this, so I need confirmation, but don't old systems need the bootloader to be the 1st x bytes?

Comment: I recall something along those lines. It's more critical for GRUBs stage 1; the part that's installed in the boot sector or beginning of a partition. I bet if GRUB2's stage 1 is installed in the boot sector, it will be able to find the rootfs containing /boot. If not, you can create a small partition for /boot, and then put swap after it. That way GRUB's stage 2 is right after the boot sector.